# Is there a reason why we see more time taken by memorystore to fetch one record out of 700 records?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

We are using a Basic tier instance of memorystore and observed during load tests that the time taken to retrieve one record is considerably high (~ 266ms) as compared to fetching 700 records (~ 168ms). Is there any reason for this?

Comment: You have not provided data that might help create an answer or suggestion.

Comment: Could you please provide information regarding on how are you running the load tests? Could you also give some example of your records? What record is retrieved slower than the others? You can also try to do the same things using the latest version of Redis, but on a VM instance and then, see if you got the same results?

Comment: In one of the use cases we are storing and retrieving a list of objects (POJOs) from memorystore using Lettuce (Java application as a microservice). When this list is having around 700 records, then we see that it is slower. Load tests included having calls to memorystore to fetch these records. For now, we are trying to use trace to see where the time taken is higher. Testing with redis in a compute-engine is also something we are planning to do. Will keep posting the progress.